# How do you style the containing div of a rendered react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of values in Divs that are rendering through react (in the compnent called cardItem). I am wanting to style the div that contains all the rendered rows I can't figure out how to do that.

I tried styling the component - but that didn't work eg

```
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h2>{current.title}</h2>
      <p>{current._id}</p>
      {cards !== null && !loading ? (
        <TransitionGroup>
          {filtered !== null
            ? filtered.map(card => (
                <CSSTransition key={card._id} timeout={500}>
                  <CardItem card={card} />
                </CSSTransition>
              ))
            : cards.map(card => (
                <CSSTransition key={card._id} timeout={500} classNames='item'>
                  <CardItem id='MytestiedID' className='collection' card={card}  />
                </CSSTransition>
              ))}
        </TransitionGroup>
      ) : (
        <Spinner />
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

I am wanting to style the output with materialize like this

```
   <div class="collection">
        <a href="#!" class="collection-item">Alvin</a>
        <a href="#!" class="collection-item active">Alvin</a>
        <a href="#!" class="collection-item">Alvin</a>
        <a href="#!" class="collection-item">Alvin</a>
      </div>
```

THE cardItem compenent is here

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import CardContext from '../../context/card/cardContext';

const CardItem = ({ card }) => {
  const cardContext = useContext(CardContext);

  const { deleteCard, setCurrentCard, clearCurrentCard } = cardContext;

  const { _id, label, summary, creatorId, documentId, linkUrl } = card;

  const onDelete = () => {
    deleteCard(_id);
    clearCurrentCard();
  };

  return (
    <div className='flex-row collection-item'>
      <div>
        <a href={linkUrl} target='_blank'>
          {label}
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>
          <button
            className='waves-effect waves-light btn-small'
            onClick={() => setCurrentCard(card)}>
            <i className='far fa-edit'></i>
          </button>
          <button
            className='waves-effect waves-light btn-small'
            onClick={() => onDelete(card)}>
            <i className='far fa-trash-alt'></i>
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

CardItem.protoTypes = {
  card: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default CardItem;
```

Comment: Please share the code of CardItem component.

Comment: if you want to style `CardItem ` you could import a style file in the component and use that.

Comment: I have included the card item component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Bootstrap: include it in the index.js file after npm.

Inline-CSS : you can create the object that contains the CSS add it to style tag =>style={customCss}.

Pass the CSS as you are passing: timeout={500}. instead of 500, passes the CSS object

Comment: Hi Harsh I am not sure I have quite worked out how to do it based on your suggestion. I tried             <CSSTransition
                  key={card._id}
                  style={cardContainerStyle}
                  timeout={500}
                  classNames='item'>
                  <CardItem card={card} />
                </CSSTransition> where containerItemStyle was set to a variable that matched the style but that didn't work

Comment: Don't do like this.

Comment: <CSSTransition key={card._id} customStyle={cardContainerStyle} timeout={500} > <CardItem card={card} /> </CSSTransition>

Now in CSSTransition component use like this
 style={customStyle}
in a tag.

Comment: Thanks I had to style the transisitionGroup component and then it worked    <TransitionGroup id='myID' className='collection'>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to so with the code, but a simple solution is to write a styled component e.g.

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  background-color: red;
  a {
    color: blue;
  }
`;
```

Then wherever you're creating your div just use `StyledDiv` instead...

Lots more good info here: https://www.styled-components.com/